# Controller throws an error that I can't trap (MVC5, C#, EF6)

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, constructor, controller

I have taken over a project written using EF6 and MVC, neither of which I am really familiar with.  I've managed to navigate my way through most of what is going on, but I need to create a new datatable / entity / service / dto / controller and view.  Again, most of this seems to be OK, but the controller doesn't work and I can't work out how to trap where the error is being raised or where the problem is.

The basic scenario is that the controller has a default action which is to return a simple string (it'll be returning a page later, but I've been cutting out unnecessary bits to identify where the problem is).  The constructor for the controller has two parameters which I understand are passed to the constructor through the dependency injection factory - this project is using Ninject.

This is the Service code:

```
public class NewThingService
{
    private readonly IRepository<NewThing> repoNewThing;

    public NewThingService(IRepository<NewThing> _repoNewThing)
    {
        this.repoNewThing = _repoNewThing;
    }

    public void Save(NewThing entity)
    {
        if (entity.Id == 0)
        {
            repoNewThing.Insert(entity);
        }
        else
        {
            repoNewThing.Update(entity);
        }
    }

    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        repoNewThing.Delete(id);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (repoNewThing != null)
        {
            repoNewThing.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Service Interface code:

```
public interface INewThingService : IDisposable
{
        void Save(NewThing entity);
        void Delete(int id);
}
```

This is the controller code:

```
public class TestController : BaseController
{
        private readonly INewThingService newThingService;
        private readonly IExistingThingService existingThingService;

        public TestController(INewThingService _newThingService, IExistingThingService _existingThingService)
        {
            this.newThingService = _newThingService;
            this.existingThingService = _existingThingService;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Test(DataTableServerSide model)
        {
            return Json("Hello", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        } 
}
```

The ExistingThing service was part of the code I inherited.  The NewThing Service is what I have added.

If I run the code as above the request is rerouted to an error handler, but there doesn't actually appear to be any associated error.  If I change the controller constructor by removing the _newThingService parameter it works fine.  If I replace the _existingThingService parameter with another service that is already in the code, that works fine too.

So, there's something wrong with how my new service is being constructed or passed to the controller constructor, but it doesn't appear to be an error as such - at least not one that VS can trap.

What's going wrong, or how do I work out what's going wrong?

Edited ----

Ninject registration of NewThingService

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
      kernel.Bind<ProjectDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
      kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(Repository<>));
      kernel.Bind(typeof(INewThingService)).To(typeof(NewThingService));
}
```

The IRepository declaration seems to be a generic one rather than one that is specific to each entity:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    TEntity FindById(object id);
    void InsertGraph(TEntity entity);
    void Update(TEntity entity);
    TEntity Update(TEntity dbEntity, TEntity entity);
    void Delete(object id);
    void Delete(TEntity entity);
    void Insert(TEntity entity);
    RepositoryQuery<TEntity> Query();
    void Dispose();
    void ChangeEntityState<T>(T entity, ObjectState state) where T : class;
    TEntity SetValues(TEntity dbEntity, TEntity entity);
    void SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Please show us your Ninject registration for `NewThingService` And also the registration for the implementation of `IRepository<NewThing>`.

Comment: Original question edited to add Ninject registration and IRepository implementation.

Comment: Please show us the registration for `IRepository`. And can you confirm whether `NewThing` is `public`?

Comment: As a short term test, please change the constructor to `public NewThingService()
    {
        this.repoNewThing = null;
    }` and put a breakpoint on the null assignment. If you run the code, does it hit the breakpoint?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. The NewThing entity declaration is public.  I've made the change to the NewThingService constructor and it does hit the breakpoint - although it doesn't do it when I expect.  The breakpoint gets hit while I am typing the URL into the address bar of the browser, before I have hit return to request the page.  Not sure if this is something clever Chrome does, or something clever MVC does, but I haven't seen (or noticed) it before ...

Comment: I've edited the original question to add the IRepository registration in the Ninject RegisterServices bit.  As I'm sure you have realised the real code is rather more complicated, so this is a cut down version ...

Comment: If it hits the breakpoint on `this.repoNewThing = null;` but _doesn't_ if you add the constructor parameter then there is either a problem with the `IRepository` registration **or** an exception in instantiating `Repository`.